# Javascript JSON not parsing properly

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to get data out of a reply given to me from a backend API. I have an object called `result` which contains the following reply from the server:

```
{
  connection: 'Keep-Alive',
  'content-language': 'en-GB',
  'content-length': '0',
  'content-type': 'text/html'
  date: 'Fri, 11 Mar 2022 06:41:06 GMT',
  'keep-alive': 'timeout=5, max=100',
}
```

I'm trying to get the 'keep-alive' part but I'm unsure how I can access it.

I've tried parsing `result` as JSON

```
const obj = JSON.parse(result)
console.log(obj)
```

But this throws the following error:

```
undefined:1
[object Object]
 ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
```

The issue seems to be that **connection** and **date** aren't within single quotes and I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: can you not directly access the keep alive part

Comment: Perhaps, but my question is, how? Result.keep-alive?

Comment: the problem is not on the single quotes of the connection or the date. try to access the property by trying directly result['connection']

Comment: Are you trying to get the value of 'keep-alive' key..??

Comment: I think the property names are wrong 'content-language' should be 'contentLanguage'

Comment: Yeah i need the value of the keep-alive key

Comment: try this then console.log(result["keep-alive"])

Comment: @alin0509 i have no access to the backend, it's from a government website

Comment: As `result` is already parsed, No need to parse it again. You can directly access via `result['keep-alive']`. I created a fiddle for your reference : https://jsfiddle.net/h3cvb6p0/

Comment: The error indicates that you don't have a JSON, not even a malformed JSON, in fact not a string at all, but a JavaScript object. You can access the properties that contain "inappropriate" characters using the bracket syntax: `result["keep-alive"]`.

Comment: Yep that did the trick!